# spring mvc <form:select data binding not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

ok so I have got a drop down rendered on my page using the code as below:

```
<form:select path="subject.subjectId" 
             items="${subjectList}" itemValue="subjectId" itemLabel="name" />
```

The html as below is rendered perfectly and the data is available on the controller when the form is submitted.

```
<select id="subject.subjectId" name="subject.subjectId">
  <option value="1">Japanese</option>
  <option value="2">Chinese</option>
  <option value="3">Maths</option>
  <option value="4">Science</option>
  <option value="5">English</option>
  <option value="6">Geography</option>
</select>
```

The only problem I face is that data-binding is not occurring when the page is rendered i.e value=5 is not set as 'selected' when the page is rendered even though subject.subjectId=5.

I am aware of a possible work around as follows but this is not an elegant solution

```
<!-- <form:select path="subject.subjectId" items="${subjectList}" itemValue="subjectId" /> -->
<form:select path="subject.subjectId">
  <c:forEach var="subject" items="${subjectList}">
   <option value="${subject.subjectId}" 
    <c:if test="${subject.subjectId eq record.subject.subjectId}">selected="selected"</c:if>>
     <c:out value=" ${subject.name}"/>
      </option>                             
   </c:forEach>
 </form:select>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe problem is with your binding variable. Are you sure you have variable by name "subject.subjectId" in your model class?

Comment: yup, I do have subject.subjectId variable in my model class. other wise the spring framework would throw me a org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException.

Comment: Can you post the form:form declaration and the controller method that handles the request?

Comment: grid, I think I see where you were getting to. I believe i got it figured out. I've update my answer as below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out while seeing sample code for the same on the internet [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm)

while my syntax for form select tag was correct, I needed to do the following

a) return a 'command' object in the ModelAndView from the controller.

b) remove the  'modelAttribute' attribute from the jsp's

And now the spring mvc form:select data binding works just as expected.